# A stone is dropped from the height of 100 meters and falls to earth. What is the velocity of the stone after one second?

Tags: calculus

[image]

**I created an instantaneous velocity equation 
t=1
s(t) = 4.9t^2**

**I am wondering where I went wrong compared to a solved example of this problem.** [image]

**I would like to know why the 4.9 is behind the limit and what happened to the -4.9. Did the person who solved this problem skip steps? That is, he did not utilize the limit law for -4.9, which would equal zero. 
Need some clarification.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cancel a factor of $h$ from the numerator and denominator before you take the limit.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{4.9(1 + h)^2 - 4.9 \cdot 1^2}{h} & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{4.9(1 + 2h + h^2) - 4.9}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{4.9 + 9.8h + 4.9h^2 - 4.9}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{9.8h + 4.9h^2}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h(9.8 + 4.9h)}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} (9.8 + 4.9h)\\
& = 9.8 + 4.9(0)\\
& = 9.8
\end{align*}

If you substitute $0$ for $h$ before you take the limit, you obtain $0/0$.

Answer (score 1):

Constant multiple law: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}[cf(x)]=c\cdot\lim_{x \to a} f(x).$

\begin{align} \lim_{h\to0}\frac{4.9(1+h)^2-4.9(1)^2}{h} &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{4.9[(1+h)^2-(1)^2]}{h} \tag{factor $4.9$} \\
&=\displaystyle\ 4.9\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(1+h)^2-1}{h} \tag{constant multiple law} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{4.9(1+h)^2-4.9(1)^2}{h}=\frac{4.9((1+h)^2-(1)^2)}{h}$. (You can write factor 4.9 before the bracket)

Then the law for Limits can be used: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(af(x))=a \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$.

Comment: So he used the limit laws and that is why the -4.9 on the left hand side disappeared?